# javascript code to change attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a javascript code that would change the value of rect when a specific event occurs. I am thinking along the lines of `document.getElementById("xxx").setAttribute`.. but I am completely stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The html code I have is this.

var x = document.getElementById("some integer").value;

```
<div id="xxx" style="position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 520px; width: 220px; height: 10px; clip: rect(0pt, 10px, 10px, 0pt); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">
```

I want to set the second value in rect, ie (10px) to xpx.

Comment: To what tag / attribute do you want to make it?

Comment: so for example it is currently rect(10px, 10px, 10px, 10px) and I want to change it to rect(10px, Zx, 10px, 10px) where z is an integer

Comment: I understand now. You want to change a *CSS property* of an element. That is different from an attribute. E.g. `style` or `id` are attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my one suggesion..

```
document.getElementById("xxx").setAttribute('onclick', function() {document.getElementById("xxx").style.clip="rect(0px 75px 75px 0px)"; });
```

or try this...

```
document.getElementById("xxx").style.clip="rect(0px 75px 75px 0px)";
```

Comment: what if I have z = 100 and I want to set the value to that. Do I do: document.getElementById("xxx").style.clip="rect(0px " +Z+"px" + "75px 0px)"?

Comment: what if I have z = 100 and I want to set the value to that. Do I do: document.getElementById("xxx").style.clip="rect(0px " +Z+"px" + "75px 0px)"?

Comment: @Paul: That is the same comment as before?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("xxx").style.clip = "rect(10px, 10px, 10px, 10px)";` should do the trick.

The `clip` property is a CSS property, so you need to use the `style` property of the DOM element to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, so that you can change any/all of the clip settings:

```
function changeClipTo(t,r,b,l,elementID) {

var clipString = "rect(" + t + "px " + r + "px " + b + "px " + l + "px)";
document.getElementById(elementID).style.clip = clipString;

}
```

That way you can have any click event supply your desired values such as onclick="changeClipTo(0,50,10,0,'someElement');" or href="javascript:changeClipTo(0,50,10,0,'someElement');"

If you don't know the dimensions ahead of time, then you could use the onclick/href to call a function which determines the value you need, then call changeClipTo() from that function, passing in the computed value(s).